# Receive UDP Broadcast

Tags: c#, udp, broadcast, udpclient

I am trying to figure out how to receive UDP packets that are being broadcast out by a set of devices. I can see them coming in using Wireshark, but cant figure out how to receive them in my application. The packets are being broadcast out to all devices on the network on the same port. I need to be able to receive them from any IP address sending them. I also have 2 NIC cards if it makes a difference. I only need to listen on 1, but I'm not sure if I have to specify that. I have tried some various things with the UdpClient, but have had no luck.

```
192.168.1.20 255.255.255.255 UDP 768 Source port: 3001 Destination port: 3002

bool done = false;

UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(3001);
IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 3002);

string received_data;
byte[] receive_byte_array;

try
{
    while (!done)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for broadcast");

        receive_byte_array = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
        Debug.WriteLine("Received a broadcast from {0}", groupEP.ToString() );
        received_data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receive_byte_array, 0, receive_byte_array.Length);
        Debug.WriteLine("data follows \n{0}\n\n", received_data);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}

listener.Close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Receive Answer to UDP Broadcast (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152489/receive-answer-to-udp-broadcast-c)

Comment: I'm not sure that post even has a working solution. Either way it did not work for me. I will add what I tried, but i'm not sure its the right approach.

Comment: I'm guessing its either the broadcast thing or the fact that I have 2 NIC cards. The UDP packets aren't being sent directly to my machine but I can see them in wireshark.